# How to protect audio files inside .obb?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

We have an app with audio files that are over 100MB in size. So we have to move them to expansion pack.

These files are individually bought via in-app billing. As they are inside the expansion pack, they are downloaded as `.obb` file which can be easily open with any ZIP tool. So any smart user can extract them without having to purchase them inside the app.

How can we prevent this? How to safely store audio files inside OBB expansion file so no one can extract them and use them before purchasing them?

Comment: I don't know the full answer, but a part of it has to do with using the JOBB tool which allows you to encrypt/unencrypt OBB files.  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jobb.html

Comment: @DeeV It works. Please post a reply so I can mark it as answer.